# How google sees the updated content daily?

Tags: seo, search-engine

I have a website with updated content daily. I have two questions:

1. How does google see this content? Do I need a SEO in this case?
2. Does the error 404 page have an influence on the ranking on the search engine. (I do not have a static page)

Answer (score 2):

So Google can "know" the content is supposed to be updated daily, it may be useful (if you don't do it yet) to implement a sitemap (and update, if necessary, dynamically). In this simemap, you can specify for each page, the update period.
This is not a constraint for Google, but it can help to adjust the frequency of indexing robots visit.
If you do, you must be "honest" with Google about times updates. If Google realizes that the frequency defined in the sitemap does not correspond to the actual frequency, it can be bad for your rankings.

404 errors (and other HTTP errors) can actually indirectly have an adverse effect on the ranking of the site. Of course, if the robot can not access content at a given moment, it can not be indexed. But scoffers, if too many problems are encountered during the visit of your site by web crawlers, Google will adjust the frequency of visits to the downside.

You can get some personalized advice and monitor the process of indexing your site using Google Webmaster Tools (and to a lesser extent, Analytics or any other tool that could monitor the web crawlers visits).

Answer (score 0):

You can see the date and time when Google last visited your page. So you can see that Google adapted your updated content or not. If you have a website with updated content daily then you can ping your website to many search engines and can also submit your site in Google.

You can make a sitemap for only those urls who have a daily updated content and submit to google webmaster tools. You can define your date and time when the url was last modified in  tag. You can also give a hint how frequently your page will likely to change under  tag. You can set high priority for the pages which are modified daily under  tag.

If you have 404 error (file not found) page then then put them in one directory and define it in your robots.txt file. So Google will not crawl that web pages and automatically it will not be indexed. It will not make any influence on your SERP ranking.